# How to create a random number in range from 65 to 74 using easy68k?

Tags: easy68k

I am doing my assignment and get stuck at this problem. Please help me. I just can create a random number from 0 to 74 .

Comment: @Louis : from 65 to 74 . Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a random number 0-9 and then add 65

Comment: in the code of this link , how can I add 65 to (0-9) ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569381/assembly-random-number-within-range-using-easy-68k-68000

Comment: `ADDQ.W      #1, D1`  change the #1 to #65